# Passing Shopify Global Variable through Additional Google Analytics Script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, shopify

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass Shopify Global Variable, such as {{ page_title }} for example, as a Custom Variable/Dimension into the "Additional Google Analytics Script" textarea?

[image]

When I look at the code on the site, it's just printing out {{ page_title }} as the value for dimension1.

Is it possible to pass Shopify Global Variables through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was a Google Tag Manager implementation, I ended up using the shopify plugin to pass the tracking code E.g. UA-01234-1 and then used Google Tag Manager (GTM) to implement the event tracking. I was able to use a dataLayer to pass variable into GA using an event that is fired on every page (a bit hackish but should do the trick).

Thanks to both @Steph Sharp and @David Lazar for your recommendations, but Shopify had its own limitations regarding what I could pass into Additional Google Analytics Script.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to render a Liquid construct in a Javascript code block. That is not going to work well for you. Best you instead render your page_title in a Liquid file, like your theme.liquid. In there, any Javascript is rendered AND Liquid is rendered, so you can combine the two.

Comment: Believe me, I'd love to put this in theme.liquid. If I were to place Google Analytics directly into theme.liquid, I would lose the ability to track across checkout.shopify.com/cart. By using Shopify's GA plugin, I get virtual pageviews in checkout.shopify.com/cart to build checkout funnel goal in GA. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: So try rendering the page_title into a variable, and then try using the value of that variable in the GA snippet. If the scope of your variable exists before Shopify renders the GA snippet, it should work.

Comment: I don't believe the scope exists before Shopify renders the GA snippet. I've setup a test -[NB-Test](http://nb-test.myshopify.com/). If you type in the console, pageTitle, you'll see a value. I've put the global variable in the GA snippet the 'Additional Google Analytics Javascript', but no go. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

David's right, I don't think you're going to have any luck with liquid tags in this javascript block.

Perhaps you could try something like this in **Additional Google Analytics Javascript**:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', document.title);
```

And in **theme.liquid**:

```
<title>{{ page_title }}</title>
```